# .htaccess redirect to subfolder, and remove it's name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, hide, subdirectory

I'm kind of noob in the world of web so my apologies... I tried many things found on SO and elsewhere, but I didn't manage to do what I want. And the Apache documentation is... well too much complete.

Basically what I want to do is redirect my domain to a subfolder. I found easy solutions for this (many different actually).

```
http://www.foo.com/
http://foo.com/
```

should redirect to `/bar` and appear as `http://foo.com/`

Using the following I got the expected result :

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/foo.com" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!bar/).*)$ bar/$1 [NC,L]
```

But I also want the subfolder as well as filenames not to appear when explicitly entered, i.e :

```
http://www.foo.com/index.html
http://foo.com/index.html
http://wwww.foo.com/bar
http://foo.com/bar
http://wwww.foo.com/bar/index.html
http://foo.com/bar/index.html
```

Should all appear as

```
http://foo.com/
```

**Is this possible ?**

Obviously using .htaccess, since I'm on a virtual host.

Thanks

Comment: In the first redirection rule the URI (`/bar/index.html`, for example) is removed, so there is nothing to be appended to the last rewrite rule. I don't think it is possible to make it general as you ask. If it worked for `/bar` is because you explicitly add it in the rule.

Answer (score 0):

As Felipe says, it's not really possible, because you lose information when you do that R=301 redirect: a hard redirect like this starts a whole new request, with no memory of the previous request.

Of course, there are ways to do similar things. The easiest is to put the original request in the query string ([here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/)'s a good rundown on how mod_rewrite works with query strings). Sure, the query string does show up in the URL, but most modern browsers hide the query string in the address bar, so if your goal is aesthethics, then this method would be workable.

If you really don't want to show any of the original query in the URL, you might use cookies by employing the [CO flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co) ([here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html#Cookie_Manipulation_Tests_mod_rewrite) are some very good examples about cookie manipulation). At any rate, the information about the original request must somehow be passed in the hard redirect.

But anyhow, and most importantly, why would you want to do something like this? It's bound to confuse humans and robots alike. Great many pages behaved like this back when frames were fashionable, and it was pretty terrible (no bookmarking, no easy linking to content, Google results with the snippet "your browser cannot handle frames", no reloading, erratic back button, oh boy, those were the days).

Speaking of which, if your content is html, you may just use a plain old iframe to achieve the effect (but I'd sincerely advise against it).